# How to display Chinese in plot's label

Tags: matlab

How to display Chinese in plot's label

我是英文版64位win7系统，在matlab中的命令行和文件中可以输入中文，但是保存再打开之后中文就变成“？？？”了。然后在plot里面xlabel中也无法使用中文，画出来的图片上就是“？？？”。
请问怎么才能在MatLab中使用中文？

Answer (score 1):

Have you Googled yourself? Try https://www.google.com/search?q=MATLAB%20%E4%B9%B1%E7%A0%81. Basically you need to use an appropriate font, depending on which OS and MATLAB you use.

You can either directly use Chinese font (such as SimSun 宋体) or properly configure font linking in registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\FontLink\SystemLink`). I wrote some articles about this in [ThemeX forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20210725001411/https://bbs.themex.net/). Pay a visit.

Comment: All the solutions on the google is just for Chinese Win7(actually I managed to display Chinese on my friend's computer with a Chinese Win7). But note my win7 is english-version. All the solutions I can google do not work on my computer